# When using jsoup in android, the site I want to connect and the site which is loaded are different

Tags: android, jsoup

I want to connect with 'http://exo.smtown.com/Board/List/10724' or 'http://exo.smtown.com/Board/List/?kind=1'(these are the same page.)

When I connect the pages, loaded content is like 'http://exo.smtown.com/Error/404.htm?aspxerrorpath=/Bo'

How can I connect the page, not the error page?

```
//doc = Jsoup.connect("http://exo.smtown.com/Board/List/10724").get();
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://exo.smtown.com/Board/List/?kind=1").get();
contents = doc.select("div");

String temp = contents.text();
Log.d("logg0","temp: "+temp);
```

I expect the output 'SM STAR Home....', but the actual output is '페이지를 찾을 수 없습니다....'

+
I tried

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
    try {
         doc = Jsoup.connect("http://exo.smtown.com/Board/List/?kind=1").timeout(30000)
         .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
         .referrer("http://www.google.com").get();
         contents = doc.select("div");
         } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
         }

         String temp = contents.text();
         Log.d("logg0","temp: "+temp);
```

+
also tried

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http%3A%2F%2Fexo.smtown.com%2FBoard%2FList%2F10724").get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the URL.

```
URLEncoder.encode(stringToBeEncoded, "UTF-8")
```

In your case:

```
Document gDoc = JSoup.connect(placesURL.format(URLEncoder.encode("http://exo.smtown.com/Board/List/?kind=1", "UTF-8"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I use
                      1) doc = Jsoup.connect("http%3A%2F%2Fexo.smtown.com%2FBoard%2FList%2F%3Fkind%3D1").get();
                  2) doc = Jsoup.connect(placesURL.format(URLEncoder.encode("http://exo.smtown.com/Board/List/?kind=1", "UTF-8"))).get();
but I still have error. In 2), I can't fix 'placeURL' to alt+enter. how can i use it?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
try {

    Jsoup.connect("http://exo.smtown.com/Board/List/?kind=1"))  / required URL
    .timeout(30000)
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
    .referrer("http://www.google.com").get()
    .select("div")
    .ownText();
}catch (Exception e) {

//handle exception

}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
      try {
           doc = Jsoup.connect("http://exo.smtown.com/Board/List/?kind=1").timeout(30000)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
             .referrer("http://www.google.com").get();
             contents = doc.select("div");
              } catch (Exception e) {
      }
      String temp = contents.text();
      Log.d("logg0","temp: "+temp);
I still have same problem

Comment: are you getting any exception or getting anything in log ?

Comment: try log with entire doc to check the data is working , if the response data is as same as HTML content of desired url, select the required data by using relevant TAGS

Comment: check entire jsoup response data once to verify with URL's